# Time Machine won't reconnect to existing working TM backup (external HDD via USB and visible in Finder)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

The external HDD was permanently powered up and connected via USB to my iMac.
I have never had an issue with it and the HDD has twice the capacity of the HD on the Mac.

The USB cable got disconnected by accident.

On reconnection it refused to back up stating 'not enough space for first back up' (even though technically this was not the first back up.

After removing the disk from Time Machine, removing the drive from finder, restarting, reconnecting the drive and opening Time Machine to 'add drive', it no longer allows this as all the folders on the HDD are greyed out.

Anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Did you have encryption enabled on your external drive originally?

Comment: It would've been the most vanilla of settings when I first set it up many years ago.